# reusing app_code dll from website in another app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project which was done in a website. moving to a web app will be a real pain.
It does get published, and thats how it gets moved to production.
as a result of the publishing, all the classes inside the app_code folder get compiled into an app_code.dll file.

I want to import this dll into another project.
it imports fine. but when i try to deckare an object from inside, my new project cant get a reference to the object.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Just don't do it. Create a class library project and encapsulate the functionality into a named dynamic link library, which is the output, that can be shared and versioned properly (as opposed to its history being mixed with the nature the website that uses it) in its own right.

Comment: Grant's spot on with this one.  Spend the extra 10 minutes doing it the right way and save yourself a lot of future pain.

Comment: aha, makes sense. and bothe the website, and the new app both refer to the dll. cool thanks

Comment: If you can add it as a project reference, rather than DLL, that can be optimal as well.  Think about this: you find a bug and need to fix the code.  Would you rather edit in one place, build it, copy the DLL, remove the old DLL, reference the new one... or just update with the bug fix and build both solutions.  Always reference by project if you *own* the code is usually a best practice.

Comment: only problem being, it's a website so I cannot add it as a project reference

Comment: You can still add it as a reference - will these be in the same solution, by the way?

Comment: yes same solution. looking good so far. my new class library compiles now (had to add some system.web references) my original website almost compiles, except the Global.asax file now needs to reference some classes in the new class library, and it says it cant find it. I tried <%@ Import Namespace="SharedCode" %> where sharedcode is my dll, but im not winning...